# Accessing GEOS functions in Python

Tags: python, spatialite, geos

***The issue:***
I am using Windows 7, 64-bit operating system with Python 3.2.  I must continue to use Python 3.2 because of a dependency with another API.  I need some functions in GEOS that are not currently supported by GDAL/OGR 1.8 and there is no port of Shapely for Python 3.2 on 64-bit Windows.

Spatialite has a beta version for 64-bits Windows but I can't get it to work and nobody in the main Stackoverflow list has a solution ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590599/sqlite-load-extension-fail-for-spatialite-in-python ).

I don't want to have to go down the route of using PostGIS to get access occassinoally to one or two functions GDAL/OGR doesn't have....

***The Question:***
SO:  Can anybody explain how to either get Spatialite working or better still, how I can use CTypes to access the functionality in the GEOS dll (I know how to connect to it but I don't understand how to pass data, say wkt, in and get my result back out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240674/using-geos-via-pythons-ctypes ).

I am VERY sorry for cross-posting but I really do need a solution.  VERY many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the 2to3 tool (see geographika's answer) to convert Shapely-1.2.13 and then manually had to change 3 lines of code to handle Python 3.x's explicit handling of string and byte encoding.  I have put this as a separate answer just for clarity and in case anybody else needs to do the same here are the lines I manually changed:

1. \geos.py (line 97)

   **old**: v = func().encode('ascii').split('-')[2]
   **error:** TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
   **new:** v = func().decode("utf-8").split('-')[2]
2. \geometry\base.py (line 60)

   **old:** EMPTY = wkb.deserialize('010700000000000000'.decode('hex'))
   **error**: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
   **new:** EMPTY = wkb.deserialize(bytes.fromhex('010700000000000000'))
3. \geometry\proxy.py (line 7)

   same as above

I then ran the same test as the [developer](http://sgillies.net/blog/564/shapely-for-python-3-0/) and got the same result.  With the above knowledge I could have done the conversion in less than 5 minutes... I just had to read up on how Python 3.x handles strings and bytes differently :).

Granted, this is not an exhaustive test but... so far so good and I hope this helps other Shapely people!

EDIT
Running the doctests gives me a few more errors but they all seem to be of the same type.. so my fix will take a bit longer and I'll not document everything here but we're on the right track now!

Comment: I have managed to eliminate all but four errors from the doctests (out of 13 or 16 if you count the three I caught prior to running doctest above). These four I think can be ignored. Three of them appear to due to differences in decimal precision between Python 3 and 2 (e.g. highly edited example: Expected (0.10000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001); Got (0.1, 0.2)).    The last remaining "error" is from raising a topology exception.  I get the correct result but a lot of extra verbage. Perhaps Python 3 is more verbose - I don't know but as long as the exception is correctly raised, I'm happy.

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks for posting your approach back here.

Comment: I have been using my ported version of Shapely for a few days now and the only issue I have encountered is the LineMerge process crashing when I have a special case of bad geometry (viz. a line of two identical points) - so, the port seems to be good... I just need to fix my geometry now :)

Answer (score 3):

In regards to Shapely and Python 3.2:

> We're not yet testing or deploying Shapely on Python 3 + Windows.
>   There's probably some non-conforming code in the shapely.geometry.geo
>   module that prevents its import.

June, 2011 - http://old.nabble.com/Shapely-package-installation-td31879542.html

So you could try getting the [Shapely source](https://github.com/sgillies/shapely/) from GitHub and 
using the automated [2to3 tool](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) to translate the code. Then rebuild for Windows (all the required files are in GitHub).

To see how to use ctypes and GEOS have a look at the Shapely source:

https://github.com/sgillies/shapely/blob/master/shapely/geos.py

However it may be time better spent trying to fix some Python inconsistencies in the Shapely source than trying to create another wrapper.

Comment: Are you using a large portion of the API or a smaller subset?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'm only really wanting one function at the moment but it is quite crucial.  I need the LineMerge tool for multi-linestrings.  I can't just append geometry manually because the order of vertices MUST correspond to the line without jumping back and forth.

Comment: @geographika: I looked at the Shapely code because I only want one function from GEOS.  I understand how to connect to GEOS but I don't understand how to pass data in and out.  I'm sorry for being a bit slow but I don't see the code in that module where this is happening.  I'm very new to CTypes so a worked example of the LineMerge function would help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on MappaGnosis's answer from December 2011, here's how I did it with Shapely 1.2.17:

Download the source, extract, and `cd` into the source directory.

Use `2to3` to update all the Python code:

```
$ find ./ -type f -name '*.py' -exec 2to3 -w -n {} \;
```

Replace all the `'rb'` with `'r'` and `'wb'` with `'w'` in `setup.py`.  This shouldn't have any consequences on a Unix-style platform, but I'm not sure about Windows.

Fix line 97 of `shapely/geos.py`:

```
- v = func()
+ v = func().decode("utf-8")
```

Fix line 87 of `shapely/geometry/base.py`:

```
- EMPTY = deserialize_wkb('010700000000000000'.decode('hex'))
+ EMPTY = deserialize_wkb(bytes.fromhex('010700000000000000'))
```

Install:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

I haven't done any testing of this hacked version to see how it works, but it does install, which is a start!

Comment: Did you run the doctests?  Have a look at my follow-up comment and you'll see that in the old version you needed to do a little more work to have Shapely fully functioning.  I'm curious as to whether this is still necessary.

Comment: @MappaGnosis - Err, good question.  I just ran the doctests and the results were littered with ERRORs and FAILs.  Many places where `bytes of integer address expected instead of str instance` and some issues related to failed comparisons between strings and byte (`'POINT'` vs. `b'POINT'`).  The final total was 15 failures and 8 errors out of 86 tests.

Comment: It sounds a similar to what I got.  When I fixed the errors/failures, Shapely has run perfectly and without problems ever since.  So, it is very doable and worth the tiny amount of pain.